# Call overloaded of Function is ambiguous

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload a print and a println function, but I am not sure on how to go about this, I am trying to emulate arduino like print and println, the function declarations below are part of a class, they all work, but I can't use the void Println(void), it gives me the following error: call of overloaded 'Println()' is ambiguous

```
void Println(void);

void Write(char data);
void Print(char data);
void Println(char data);

void Write(uint8_t data);
void Print(uint8_t data = 0, uint8_t base = 10);
void Println(uint8_t data = 0, uint8_t base = 10);

void Write(uint16_t data);
void Print(uint16_t data = 0, uint8_t base = 10);
void Println(uint16_t data = 0, uint8_t base = 10);
```

I understand why the error happens, but I am not sure how to go about this, I want to be able to print, println and write all data types.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the purpose of giving `data` a default value?

Comment: Calling `Print()` will also be ambiguous.

Comment: If you pass an literal `int` value, like e.g. `23`, which overload should be called?

Comment: ```void Println(char data);
void Println(uint8_t data = 0, uint8_t base = 10);```
`uint8_t` and `char` is absolutely identical types. only one way to do it is splitting functions on `PrintlnNumber` and `Println`

Comment: btw, there are no need to implement `Print` for 8-bit numbers, just overload it for 32 and 64

Comment: `void Println(void)` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I assume it means to print an end of line.

Comment: is it different implementations?

Comment: println(void) should only print and new line char, fixed all by removing the default value for the data argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand why the error happens, but I am not sure how to go about this, I want to be able to print, println and write all data types.

Remove the default value of the first argument from some of those declarations.

```
void Print(uint8_t data, uint8_t base = 10);
void Println(uint8_t data, uint8_t base = 10);
```

and

```
void Print(uint16_t data, uint8_t base = 10);
void Println(uint16_t data, uint8_t base = 10);
```